# What are the files required by nss-passwords?

Tags: firefox

I want to access my Mozilla Firefox passwords with the command-line without the complete profile folder.

What are the files required by nss-passwords?

Answer (score 1):

The three required files are `cert8.db`, `key3.db`, `signons.sqlite`.

If they are all in a given folder, one can the use:

```
nss-passwords -d /media/9EKE-GTE7/ stackexchange
```